# Event Action is not found while creating Audience in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, target-audience

I created 2 events for submitting of two buttons "Yes" (with outbound click) and "No" (to close optin form)

i added tags to both of these buttons and they fire events accordingly in real-time events

however when I try to create two audiences for both of this events, Google Analytics offers to choose only "Yes button event" from the list but there is no "No button event" available to choose for the audience.

Also it offers me to choose from other Events that no longer exist.

here is 40 seconds video to see it if needed
https://www.loom.com/share/9b553c404b224a20af41845a2689a8b7

if I just type the name of event action even though it doesn't find it, will it start create the audience or what could be the problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read up on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Start by clearly explaining your problem, and what you have tried so far posting your code (properly formatted). Avoid including links to tutorials or videos - links should be used only as means to provide a documentation reference.

Comment: You can find this action creating a segment? Probably has not yet been acquired by the Google system to appear in automatic suggestions but if you write it manually it works.